# How to delete decimals from labels in plots made with the scales package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, decimal, scale

I made a plot where the fill bar is on a logarithmic scale. By default, labels appear in the format `1e+01`, `1e+02`, etc. I chose to modify the labels using the `scales` package, using the `label_number()` function. However, the values `0.1`, `10`, `1000` and `100000` appear with extra decimal places. Is there any way to show these numbers without the additional decimal places?

I would like a sequence like this: `0.001`, `0.1`, `10`, `1000`, and `100000`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

X <- 0
Y <- 0
Z <- 10

DF <- data.frame(X, Y, Z)

ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = X,
           y = Y,
           fill = Z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu",
                       trans = 'log10',
                       limits = c(0.001, 100000),
                       labels = label_number(big.mark = ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `?label_number`, you can specify arguments from `base::format()`. Here the trick is `drop0trailing = T`.

`big.mark = ""` is used to remove empty space in the thousandth position.

```
ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = X,
           y = Y,
           fill = Z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu",
                       trans = 'log10',
                       limits = c(0.001, 100000),
                       labels = label_number(drop0trailing = T, big.mark = ""))
```

[image]